# Sync music between two computers using iCloud

Tags: icloud

I have a Macbook and a Mac Mini. I have set my target for my files to the same iCloud folder on both devices.

I am importing all my old CDs to my iCloud folder.

How do I successfully sync the two together now? As I understand it, there is a file on the local drive that also keeps track of the titles.

Comment: Music syncs using "iCloud Music Library." If you have Apple Music / iTunes Match this includes files you've recorded and added to your library yourself. I've never tried syncing music by putting the target folder in iCloud Drive.

Comment: @Ezekiel, I guess I am struggling with matching my files.

Comment: What exactly is your setup? Do you have an iCloud folder with ripped CDs, or do you have your music in Apple Music and use iCloud Music Library for syncing?

Comment: @nohillside I have a shared folder in iCloud that I am ripping CDs to

Comment: I removed the Apple Music references, they don’t apply if you only use iCloud folders. Having said that: iCloud syncs automatically, what exactly does not sync in your case?

Comment: @brentwpeterson Are you trying to use the Music app in this setup?